# Should I use social logins for the design of an insurance (home) quote and buy site with self-serve?

Tags: social-interfaces, social

I'm designing an insurance site. 
When users create a quote + select to save, they are asked to create an account. 
When users buy a policy, they have to create an account so they can manage their policy online.

My question is whether i should add social logins to the site? so users could save their quote using their social login for example or login to their portal with their social logins?

Is it relevant to add them? I keep reading conflicting views and general advice is only add them if the site itself is social....

Comment: I'd step back and ask why the necessity to create an account at all. Typically, from a UX POV, it's not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

I think a good question to ask is, "Is this appropriate for your type of audience?"

I'm not sure if your end user are clients or brokers, but the thought of a professional brokerage or even a client logging in with their Facebook account seems strange to me.

It's like a bank with social logins. The sensitivity of this type of website seems unnatural to combine it with social media.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the sensitivity of the data seems unnatural combined with social media. Insurance is personal, but if you were going to extend the conversation and offer the option to post "I just saved a bunch of money on my homeowners' insurance!" to your social media outlets, I suppose I could see it. Never expected my tax preparation software to allow me to LOG IN with my FB account, but posting that I'm now done filing my taxes? Yup. I can see that. Same thing with getting a quote.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, the usage of social logins makes only sense if you use some kind of functionality. If you just use them as container, so that the user doesn't require to create a new user / password, it leeds to a strange feeling for the user: "why should I connect my Facebook login to the site, when the site must not use any information from my Facebook profile?".

Regarding the "only if the site is social" I do not agree. As I mentioned above, you could make usage of the social platform in your application, then a combined login would make sense, even if your site is not a social platform or similar.

Keep also in mind, that by using some services as login provider, the application must ask the user for access to certain resources (e.g. allow the application to post on your timeline, ...). If this is wrong configured, it could prevent user from using your service, as they do not feel comfortable to let the application get control over certain part of their social profile.

All in all if you add them, I would all the time provide a normal way to login (e.g. create a new login to store the data). This provides an alternative way if a) someone doesn't have any social login
b) the user would not like to connect the social service with your application.

Cheers Thierry